# Different address using Create2 due to difference in byteCode(type(ERC1967Proxy).creationCode and ethers.getContractFactory("ERC1967Proxy").bytecode

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, openzeppelin-contracts, create2, account-abstraction

I am currently facing an issue while trying to calculate the address of a SimpleAccount contract using getCreate2Address() from ethers.utils in JavaScript. I noticed that the address I receive is different from the one obtained by calling simpleAccountFactory.getAddress() with the same parameters (owner and salt).

To investigate further, I examined the code from the GitHub repository: https://github.com/eth-infinitism/account-abstraction. Specifically, I looked at the SimpleAccountFactory.sol contract and its associated SimpleAccount.sol implementation.

Here is a brief overview of the code based on my understanding:
SimpleAccountFactory(https://github.com/eth-infinitism/account-abstraction/blob/develop/contracts/samples/SimpleAccountFactory.sol)

SimpleAccount(https://github.com/eth-infinitism/account-abstraction/blob/develop/contracts/samples/SimpleAccount.sol)
SimpleAccountFactory.sol is a factory contract responsible for deploying the SimpleAccount implementation. When SimpleAccountFactory is deployed, it also deploys SimpleAccount as per its constructor.

The factory contract has two methods:

a. `createAccount(address owner, uint salt)`: This method deploys the ERC1967Proxy contract, which points to the SimpleAccount implementation. The ERC1967Proxy constructor requires the implementationAddress and data as parameters. Here, data represents the initialization code to call after deploying ERC1967Proxy, which delegates that to the SimpleAccount implementation to set the contract owner.

b. `getAddress(address owner, uint salt)`: This method uses Create2.computeAddress() to calculate the address of the contract based on the owner and salt arguments. It does this by utilizing the CREATE2 library from OpenZeppelin (@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Create2.sol) and calling the internal function computeAddress(bytes32 salt, bytes32 bytecodeHash).

To address my issue, I attempted to calculate the address of the SimpleAccount using getCreate2Address() from ethers.utils. However, I obtained a different address compared to the one returned by simpleAccountFactory.getAddress().

To debug further, I added some additional methods to the SimpleAccountFactory.sol contract to retrieve the bytecode (creationCode) and the hash of the initCode (computed as keccak256(creationCode + constructionParameter)). Upon inspecting these values, I discovered that the bytecode returned from the contract (`type(ERC1967Proxy).creationCode`) differs from the bytecode generated during code compilation (`ERC1967ProxyArtifact.bytecode`).

To illustrate the issue, I have provided a modified version of the SimpleAccountFactory.sol contract and a script that I used to investigate the problem.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or insights into why I am receiving different bytecode values. Thank you in advance for your help.
Modified SimpleAccountFactory.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.12;

import "../../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Create2.sol";
import "../../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/ERC1967/ERC1967Proxy.sol";

import "../SimpleAccount.sol";

/**
 * A sample factory contract for SimpleAccount
 * A UserOperations "initCode" holds the address of the factory, and a method call (to createAccount, in this sample factory).
 * The factory's createAccount returns the target account address even if it is already installed.
 * This way, the entryPoint.getSenderAddress() can be called either before or after the account is created.
 */
contract SimpleAccountFactory {
    SimpleAccount public immutable accountImplementation;

    constructor(IEntryPoint _entryPoint) {
        accountImplementation = new SimpleAccount(_entryPoint);
    }

    /**
     * create an account, and return its address.
     * returns the address even if the account is already deployed.
     * Note that during UserOperation execution, this method is called only if the account is not deployed.
     * This method returns an existing account address so that entryPoint.getSenderAddress() would work even after account creation
     */
    function createAccount(
        address owner,
        uint salt
    ) public returns (SimpleAccount ret) {
        address addr = getAddress(owner, salt);
        uint codeSize = addr.code.length;
        if (codeSize > 0) {
            return SimpleAccount(payable(addr));
        }
        ret = SimpleAccount(
            payable(
                new ERC1967Proxy{salt: bytes32(salt)}(
                    address(accountImplementation),
                    abi.encodeCall(SimpleAccount.initialize, (owner))
                )
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * calculate the counterfactual address of this account as it would be returned by createAccount()
     */
    function getAddress(
        address owner,
        uint salt
    ) public view returns (address) {
        return
            Create2.computeAddress(
                bytes32(salt),
                keccak256(
                    abi.encodePacked(
                        type(ERC1967Proxy).creationCode,
                        abi.encode(
                            address(accountImplementation),
                            abi.encodeCall(SimpleAccount.initialize, (owner))
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
    }

    function getERC1967ProxyBytecodeHash(
        address owner
    ) public view returns (bytes32) {
        return
            keccak256(
                abi.encodePacked(
                    type(ERC1967Proxy).creationCode,
                    abi.encode(
                        address(accountImplementation),
                        abi.encodeCall(SimpleAccount.initialize, (owner))
                    )
                )
            );
    }

    function getERC1967ProxyCreationCode() public pure returns (bytes memory) {
        return type(ERC1967Proxy).creationCode;
    }

    function getSalt(uint salt) public pure returns (bytes32) {
        return bytes32(salt);
    }

    function getERC1967ProxyConstructorCode(
        address owner
    ) public view returns (bytes memory) {
        return
            abi.encode(
                address(accountImplementation),
                abi.encodeCall(SimpleAccount.initialize, (owner))
            );
    }
}
```

Here is the script I used

```
          const ethersSigner = ethers.provider.getSigner()
          const entryPoint = process.env.ENTRY_POINT_CONTRACT!
          owner = await ethersSigner.getAddress()
          console.log(owner)

          //getting required artifacts 
          
          //ERC1967Proxy is the contract which gets deployed when creating new SimpleAccount
          const ERC1967ProxyArtifact = await ethers.getContractFactory("ERC1967Proxy"); 

          // SimpleAccount is an implementation of smart contract wallet deployed when SimpleAccountFactory is deployed
          const simpleAccountArtifact = await ethers.getContractFactory("SimpleAccount");

          //SimpleAccountFactory is factory for deploying ERC1967Proxy linked to SimpleAccount Implementation
          const simpleAccountFactoryArtifact = await ethers.getContractFactory("SimpleAccountFactory");
          
          //Deploying SimpleAccountFactory, It will also deploy SimpleAccount Implementation from Constructor
          const simpleAccountFactory =  await new SimpleAccountFactory__factory(ethersSigner).deploy(entryPoint);
          
          //Getting the SimpleAccount Implementation Address
          const simpleAccountImplAddress = await simpleAccountFactory.accountImplementation()
          
          console.log(`SimpleAccountFactory Address: ${simpleAccountFactory.address}`)
          console.log(`SimpleAccount Implementation Address: ${simpleAccountImplAddress}`)
          

          const bytecodeHash = await simpleAccountFactory.getERC1967ProxyBytecodeHash(owner) 
          const proxyCreationCode = await simpleAccountFactory.getERC1967ProxyCreationCode() 
          const constructorCode = await simpleAccountFactory.getERC1967ProxyConstructorCode(owner) 
          const salt = await simpleAccountFactory.getSalt(0) 

          console.log(`/******************************************/`)
          console.log(`/********** Values from Contract ************/`)
          console.log(`/******************************************/`)
          console.log('')
          console.log(`ByteCodeHash : ${bytecodeHash}`)

          const derivedAccountAddress = getCreate2Address(
            simpleAccountFactory.address, //Factory Contract 
            salt, //ethers.constants.HashZero,// ethers.utils.hexZeroPad('0x0', 32), // salt ethers.constants.HashZero
            bytecodeHash
          );

          console.log(`Create2 Derived Address using values from Contract :${derivedAccountAddress} `)
         
          console.log("")
          console.log(`/******************************************/`)
          
          // Deriving SimpleAccount Address using Create2 offChain

          // Attaching SimpleAccount Interface to deployed Address
          const simpleAccount = simpleAccountArtifact.attach(simpleAccountImplAddress)

          // ERC1967Proxy takes two parameter while deploying (implementation, data)
          const encodedConstructorInitCode = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(['address','bytes'],
          [
            simpleAccountImplAddress,
            simpleAccount.interface.encodeFunctionData('initialize', [owner])
          ])

          // Calculating InitCodeHash keccak256(contractByteCode+ConstructorCode)
          const initCodeHash = ethers.utils.keccak256(
            ethers.utils.solidityPack(
              ['bytes', 'bytes'],
              [ERC1967ProxyArtifact.bytecode, encodedConstructorInitCode]
            ),
          );
          console.log(`/******************************************/`)
          console.log(`/************** OffChain Values *************/`)
          console.log(`/******************************************/`)
          console.log('')
          console.log(`ByteCodeHash : ${initCodeHash}`)
          // console.log("proxyCreationCode from Contract :"+proxyCreationCode)
          // console.log("getInitCode from Contract :"+constructorCode)
          // console.log("getSalt from Contract :"+salt)
          const derivedAccountAddress2 = getCreate2Address(
            simpleAccountFactory.address, //Factory Contract 
            salt, //ethers.constants.HashZero,// ethers.utils.hexZeroPad('0x0', 32), // salt ethers.constants.HashZero
            initCodeHash
          );

          console.log(`Create2 Derived Address using Offchain values: ${derivedAccountAddress2} `)
         
          console.log("")
          console.log("Second Way ")
          
          const implementationAddress = simpleAccountImplAddress
          const initializeCall = new Interface(SimpleAccount__factory.abi).encodeFunctionData('initialize', [owner])
          const initCodeData = await new ERC1967Proxy__factory(ethersSigner).getDeployTransaction(implementationAddress, initializeCall).data!
          console.log(`ByteCodeHash : ${keccak256(initCodeData)}`)
          console.log(`Generated Address : ${getCreate2Address(simpleAccountFactory.address, ethers.constants.HashZero, keccak256(initCodeData))}`)
          console.log("")
          console.log(`/******************************************/`)
```

Output I received when running this locally on hardhat node:

```
0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266
SimpleAccountFactory Address: 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3
SimpleAccount Implementation Address: 0xa16E02E87b7454126E5E10d957A927A7F5B5d2be
/******************************************/
/********** Values from Contract ************/
/******************************************/

ByteCodeHash : 0xaae4cef5d37af27a91ad34fa0d4df5cb3149421e666b38ecdfd09efd2376bbfd
Create2 Derived Address using values from Contract :0x0c902727bd19464070135aB346b8116f9567D02C 

/******************************************/
/******************************************/
/************** OffChain Values *************/
/******************************************/

ByteCodeHash : 0x9a954548fa2f84c4baa023ec532a496c7f7e090bcb44d8b057f62e5ebf68cefd
Create2 Derived Address using Offchain values: 0xCf125899cAdA2B3c691f36FB6795531556A8051f 

Second Way 
ByteCodeHash : 0x9a954548fa2f84c4baa023ec532a496c7f7e090bcb44d8b057f62e5ebf68cefd
Generated Address : 0xCf125899cAdA2B3c691f36FB6795531556A8051f

/******************************************/
Actual Account's Proxy address: 0x0c902727bd19464070135aB346b8116f9567D02C
```